# SqlAlchemy check if relationship property is in list

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables:
1) Shop that have column item that have relationship with the second table
2) Items table - have some details like brand etc..

I am trying to make query that will give me all raws from shop where the brand is in list of brands.

```
brands = self.session.query(Items).filter(Items.brand.in_(list))
self.session.query(Shop).filter((Shop.active_item== True) &
                                        (Shop.item.has(brands)))
```

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy still does not support in_ with objects. Hence you can try two ways.

1. get the brand ids and filter them with in_ in the second query.

   ```
   brands = self.session.query(Items).filter(Items.brand.in_(list))
   brand_ids = [obj.id for obj in brands]  
   self.session.query(Shop).filter((Shop.active_item== True) &
                                        (Shop.item.id.in_(brand_ids)))
   ```
2. filter with the brand list it self.

   ```
   self.session.query(Shop).filter((Shop.active_item== True) &
                                        (Shop.item.brand.in_(list)))
   ```

This is just out of my head. But I you can get the idea.

Cheers.